# how to use Url.Content("~\stuff\hi.jpg") in controller's code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need the result of an `Url.Content("~\stuff\")` in controller's code,

How do I get this?

Comment: Please choose a correct answer as "your answer". The current selected answer is completely misleading for the question asked.

Comment: The accepted answer is not the correct answer (the OP acknowledges this). Scroll to see the highest-voted answer (as of April 2016) instead, or jump to it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5243484/2091410).

Comment: it mentions `Url.Content` inside controller which I ended up using at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the physical file path on disk:

```
Server.MapPath("~\stuff\")
```

Controllers also include a urlHelper, available as `Url`, but that may not be what you need.

What is the result that you expect?

**Edit:** As per your request for a FilePath, `Url.Content("~\stuff\")` should work? Unless you use a really old ASP.net MVC that did not have a Url property on controllers.

Comment: I think because I ended up using Url.Content

Answer (score 40):

in service code (i.e. away from the controllers), you can use:

```
string returnUrl = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/stuff/");
```

mvc1-3 exposes the `Url.Content("~/stuff/");` from the UrlHelper in System.Web.Mvc, which can be readily used in your controller code.

**[edited]** - to make subtle distinction in the `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/stuff/")` usage.

Comment: This worked for me, I couldn't use the Url.Content("~/stuff/"); outside Controller classes even with the proper Usings and namespaces ... Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Inside the controller action you could use the [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.url.aspx) property:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var url = Url.Content("~/stuff/");
    ...
}
```

Also notice the usage of `/` instead of `\` when dealing with relative urls.

Answer (score 4):

MVC 3 exposes a [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.url%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property on the controller as a [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx) object

```
var url = Url.Content("~/stuff/");
```

I'm not sure if it is available in older MVC versions but if not you can create your own

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(ControllerContext.RequestContext);
var url = urlHelper.Content("~/stuff/");
```

Comment: Why creating a new instance of the url helper when there is already one available?

Comment: @Darin I've updated my answer, I couldn't find any information on if the `Url` property is available to older MVC versions. Otherwise the answer is in the question so I thought that may be reason the OP is asking.

Comment: this property [has been around since ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.url(VS.90).aspx).

Comment: actually darin, you're correct there. i was (in my answer) alluding to how i would do it in service code.